# Adding Progressive Web Application to homescreen

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I've just finished watching a presentation from Google I/O 2016 about Progressive Web Applications. Safe to say I'm pretty excited about them.

I did have one question in regards to a user adding the icon to their home screen. Is the user able to hide the icon in the app drawer (for Android devices obviously) like they would be able to do with a native app? or must the icon stay on their home screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UDPATE:** The Chrome Dev channel (v56) now supports **Enable improved add to Home screen**. Note the flag isn't working in Chrome Canary (no installation). I tested this on Android M. To enable it:

1. From the Chrome Dev app, navigate to `chrome://flags/#enable-improved-a2hs`.
2. Click **Enable**.
3. Navigate to `chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks`.
4. Click **Enable**.
5. Relaunch browser.
6. Navigate to https://paperplanes.world.
7. Click **Add To Homescreen** in the app banner.
8. Click **Install** at the app installation screen.
9. Click **Done**.
10. Observe the "Paper Planes" icon on the homescreen AND in the app drawer.

---

<del>No, the PWA app icon can only live on the homescreen.</del>

<del>You could manage the icon as any other homescreen icon, including grouping it into a folder on the homescreen, or removing it.</del>

Comment: I can't find this flag on Chrome v 54.0.2840.85.

Shouldn't it be available here?

Comment: Chrome Dev is currently 56. I'm not sure exactly which version the flag was added, but apparently it's after 54 :)

Comment: Thanks Tony, got it now. Love the new install style :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently PWAs only support adding their icons to an Android device's home screen. However at [Chrome Dev Summit 2016](https://developer.chrome.com/devsummit/), it was [announced](https://youtu.be/eI3B6x0fw9s?t=21m4s) that the Chrome dev channel will soon be getting experimental support for "installing" PWAs.

There will be a new option added to `chrome://flags` "enable improved add to home screen" that when enabled make it so that installing a PWA gets it listed on the app drawer and on the Settings all apps list.